# VBA code to delete files in a directory that contains specific characters

Tags: vba, excel

I need help in a VBA macro that'll delete files in a directory that contains more than 2 "_" and is older than 3 months old, however there are some folders & sub folders in the directory that must not be touched or modified.

E.g, Hi_Thanks_for_your_help *or* Hi_Thank_You etc.

```
Const DIR = "x"
Const MAX_AGE = 3 ' Unit: Months

Dim oFSO
Dim aExclude

Sub XLS()

aExclude = Array("x")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
deleteFiles oFSO.GetFolder(DIR)
Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub


'=================================
Function isExclude(sPath)
    Dim s, bAns
    bAns = False
    For Each s In aExclude
        If InStr(1, sPath, s, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            bAns = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    isExclude = bAns
End Function
'=================================
Function isOldFile(fFile)
    ' Old file if "MAX_AGE" months before today is greater than the file modification time
    isOldFile = (DateAdd("m", -MAX_AGE, Date) > fFile.DateLastModified)
End Function
```

This is the furthest i got with a code, what i'm lacking is how to check if a file name consists more than 2 "_" and if so & it's older than 3 months old = delete.

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim pathname As String = ""

    If fileNameCount("file_name") And DateDiff("m", NOW(), FileDateTime(pathname)) > 3 Then ' if '_' is more than 2 count and more than 3 months old, then delete
        ' if true delete file codes starts here
        ......
    End If

    Public Function fileNameCount(filename As String) As Boolean

        fileNameCount = False
        Dim count As Long
        Dim temp() As String

        temp = Split(filename, "_")

        count = UBound(temp, 1)

        If (count > 2) Then
            fileNameCount = True
        End If

    End Function
```

I have written portion of the codes for you, the method fileNameCount will return you true / false for number of counts of '_', I'm using DateDiff to get the difference of the month of the file. Therefore I'm detecting on the both conditions, if both statement are true condition then you should proceed on with your deletion of file codes which I didn't write for that.

What you need to do is

1) Pass in the "file_name" argument which you need to think on how to get the file name
2) Pass in the right pathname of the file
3) Write the code for deletion of files

Anyway, I didn't test out the code so it might have some error(s). Hope this will help what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To get the amount of `"_"` in a file, I would use something similar to this:

```
Dim a
Dim c As Integer

a = Split("File_Name_Here", "_")
c = Ubound(a)
```

Using this, you know that if the filename gets split into 3 or more substrings, there were 2 `"_"` in the filename. As for the age of the file, `FileDateTime("FilePath")` will get you the created date or the last modified date.

Comment: And how do i add this to the code? Sorry i'm still new to VBA for excel. Appreciate the help! :)